# A phrase equal to "ignoring a person on purpose to make him/her mad"

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

Is there any expression or phrase to mean:

> Not showing any reaction to one's insults,noises,accuses,provocative actions,comments and silly behaviors on purpose and make him/her mad.

We have some expressions in Persian to describe this reaction but I couldn't find in English dictionaries unless ignoring or neglecting which are too general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We call this "giving someone *the silent treatment*".  When you purposefully ignore someone, no matter what they do, to simply make them angry with you, it's called "the silent treatment".

> Person 1: What's up with Mark and Amy? He keeps trying to get her attention but she won't say a word.
>
> Person 2: He forgot her birthday so she's giving him the silent treatment.

Comment: There's also "giving someone the cold shoulder" or "[snub](http://thesaurus.com/browse/snub?s=t)".

Comment: @BillFranke That seems like an answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Only a partial answer that can be added to Wendi's. I didn't think of hers & she didn't think of mine, but she answered first, so........ I don't like to give a competing answer unless I think the other(s) is(are) wrong or seriously inadequate.

Comment: A real Gentleman! :)) (-Am I going to be a flatterer? -No, I am honest!.. -Do I want upvotes for nothing? -No, I am able to gather them by my own attempts! :")) )

Comment: @BillFranke: Although WendiKidd's answer is fantastic, I think your should either edit her answer to include your suggestion, or should write it in your own answer. There's nothing wrong with having lots of answers to a question when the different answers are valid. Don't think of it as "competing". Think about it being an "additional answer to the question".

Comment: @Matt: Okay, I'll add an answer.

Comment: @BillFranke The reason I suggested to add an answer is that you are suggesting a single word and a phrase; none of those were suggested in this answer. The fact you are suggesting a verb with the requested meaning makes the answer quite important not to be left as comment.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thank you for this explanation. I didn't think of the _single word_ aspect, but that always does come up, doesn't it? Good call.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Wendi Kidd's answer of "giving someone *the silent treatment*", there's also "giving someone **the cold shoulder**" or "[*snubbing*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/snub?s=t) someone".

Comment: +1, these are great expressions that didn't come to mind when I wrote my answer :)